# Syntax error defining links in DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm generating links with simple DXL scripts.  Can someone explain why the designated line below throws errors?  The errors are (ignore the line number)

> -E- DXL:  incorrect arguments for (->)
>   -E- DXL:  incorrectly concatenated tokens
>   -E- DXL:  incorrect arguments for function (object)

My interpretation of the info in the DXL RefManual (9.3) was that both "<-" and "->" were legal for any method of defining the objects.  What's actually happening here?

```
Module modin = edit("/Carl.Witthoft/tablemix",true,false)
if (null(modin)) ack("Error!in")
Module modout = edit("/Carl.Witthoft/77GRCRcopy",true,false)
if (null(modout)) ack("Error!out")

object(479,modout) <- object(22,modin)
// next line throws error
object(22,modin) -> object(479,modout)
/* the following will execute successfully:
Object obin =object(21,modin)
Object obout = object(702,modout)
obout <- obin
obout -> obin
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the following line:

```
object(22,modin) -> object(479,modout)
```

to

```
(object(22,modin)) -> (object(479,modout))
```

should work. The '->' operator can be a little finicky.